# DotNetNuke : Pass a data from one module to another module

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

In am developing a website by using DotNetNuke, module by module. 
In a page (tab), I have 3 modules. 2 modules are the same module which are Form modules, however I name it for different name (Section A and Section B).

In my Button modules it involve processing of Section A and Section B how can I pass data from Form Modules with Section A and Section B into Button modules within same page (Tabs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you need the `IModuleCommunicator` and the `IModuleListener` interfaces.

**On the module that will send data:**

```
public partial class View : Module1, IModuleCommunicator
{
    public event ModuleCommunicationEventHandler ModuleCommunication;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            sendDataToOtherModule("This is a test.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(this, ex);
        }
    }

    public void sendDataToOtherModule(string valueToSend)
    {
        ModuleCommunicationEventArgs mcea = new ModuleCommunicationEventArgs();

        mcea.Target = "TheOtherModule";
        mcea.Value = valueToSend;

        ModuleCommunication(this, mcea);
    }
}
```

**On the module that will receive the data**

But you could use this code in every module and check the `Target`.

```
public partial class View : Module2, IModuleListener
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //module code
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(this, ex);
        }
    }

    public void OnModuleCommunication(object sender, ModuleCommunicationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Target == "TheOtherModule")
        {
            Label1.Text = e.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Add `using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.Communications` on both modules.

Comment: But I am in the same module which are Form Module, just different Module title. Can I send data between 2 Form module with different title? Because in my scenario Form Module A, I have DataSet A and in Form Module B, I have DataSet B. I want to get all the DataSet value of Form Module within in a same Tab

Comment: This works for all modules. It sends an `object` to the other module so you can just cast it back to the original datatype and work with that,